# How to get navigator.share() tested in puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, share, chromium, navigator

I am using puppeteer to get some automated tests done, but cannot figure out how to test if the navigator.share() function is running properly after the user click.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test that `navigator.share()` function was called, you can mock it in browser context and check if mock function was called after action, like

```js
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window['isNavigatorShareCalled'] = false;
    window.navigator.share = async (data) => {
      window['isNavigatorShareCalled'] = true;
      window['shareData'] = data;
    };
  });

  await page.goto(yourSite);

  await page.waitForSelector(trigger).then(el => el.click());

  const isShareCalled = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return window['isNavigatorShareCalled'];
  });

  expect(isShareCalled).toBe(true);
  // check data if needed
```

If you need to call native share then, you can do it inside mock.